# TeamViewer is prompting to change password when session ends, can it be stopped?

Tags: teamviewer

I'm finishing up preparing for a TeamViewer rollout for our organisation and there's a few things I'd like to tidy up before doing so.

After finishing a connection to a user, the user is prompted with a box:

The connection to X has ended. Your connection partner can establish a new connection with the old password as long as you don't change it (or close TeamViewer).

Can this prompt be disabled at all?

Comment: You have the commercial Teamviewer (if not you should). Why not ask their support directly?

Comment: We do, they told me to read the manual which didn't help. I've actually sorted it so will answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up some policy into TeamViewer Management Console, it is quite simple.

If you haven't, you should think about doing it ;-)

- Navigate to https://login.teamviewer.com/nav/deploy/policies
- Edit your policy
- Choose "Random password after each session" setting
- Set the value of your choice, beside "Show confirmation"

Enjoy !